# Banned for asking questions and cannot undelete question

Tags: support

I have been banned from asking questions on StackOverflow so asked here for advice and was advised to edit my posts to make them better but have a problem as some of my posts have been deleted by community and I cannot undelete or edit them.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a link to your deleted question please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20452749/circumstances-in-which-to-use-an-exception-java

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay, I responded to your flags and undeleted the question that Community ♦ (AKA the biggest serial killer on the network) automatically culled because they were down voted, unanswered and getting rather old. You're right, as the Community user is technically a moderator, folks can't undelete what it deletes.

I'm not entirely sure that's what we want in these circumstances, folks can't go back and fix their old questions if they can't, you know, *edit* them and make them eligible for voting again. I don't know if we can somehow *not* enforce the 'only mod can undelete' thing when automatically culling posts, I'm going to find out.

You also had a wildly broad (however, seemingly naive) question about when to use objects in languages that offer objects - you probably would not have been able to edit that sufficiently to make any kind of meaningful difference, and it was like a lead weight around your ankle when it comes to working out of the block. I disassociated it from your account, which effectively lifted the block.

Since you're actually *here* and trying to get the block lifted, I'm certain that you'll take steps to ensure that you don't find yourself on the wrong end of it again. And, well, what the heck, it's that time of year.

Answer (score -1):

> some of my posts have been deleted by community

Because [the Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) is a moderator, your question can only be undeleted by a moderator. You can flag your question for moderator attention and tell that the question should be undeleted for editing.