# Banned from asking question, but cannot improve existing question because of deletion

Tags: support, post-ban

I have my questions deleted after realizing the below standard quality, but still got banned.

similar case in [Banned for asking questions and cannot undelete question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214010/banned-for-asking-questions-and-cannot-undelete-question) but it seems I need to open this question for moderators to undelete those?

Comment: Unless there are extenuating circumstances (or if they are unsalvageable), a mod will probably undelete your questions. However, all forms of community assistance lead to unblocking, so you're welcome to help out everywhere!

Comment: I think I have like total of -4 down vote in questions i've asked, and much more reputations from answering, but I still cannot post, would be nice to know how much more help I need to offer to lift the ban.

Comment: The ban seems lifted and questions are undeleted, thanks to mod :)

Comment: @miushock I can't lift a ban; you improving your questions does that. I only undeleted them. In the future, don't delete your bad questions; improve them. Deleting them only keeps you from being able to improve them, it doesn't affect the ban algorithm.